# Why MDCard not able to add on_touch_down in KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have implemented following. There are two button in bottomsheet. When click on first button it go from Main screen to first screen. On first screen, clicking on right-top button will create 10 cards.

But when try to add `on_touch_down` then it get crashed. I have added `toast` `print` and also some function but nothing is working.

So what will be the solution for this? Thanks

**main.py**
I have commented `on_touch_down = toast('clicked')`. It work without that but when uncomment it then app get crashed. How to implement this? So that card become clickable.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivymd.uix.bottomsheet import MDGridBottomSheet
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from build_string import helper_string

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.dialog = ""

        self.sm = Builder.load_string(helper_string)
        return self.sm

    def callback_for_main_menu_items(self, *args):
        toast(args[0])
        if args[0] == 'First':
            self.sm.current = "first_screen"
        if args[0] == 'Home':
            self.sm.current = "main_screen"

    def show_main_grid_bottom_sheet(self):
        self.bottom_sheet_main_menu = MDGridBottomSheet()

        data = {
            "First": "page-first",
            "Home": "home",
        }
        for item in data.items():
            self.bottom_sheet_main_menu.add_item(
                item[0],
                lambda x, y=item[0]: self.callback_for_main_menu_items(y),
                icon_src=item[1],
            )
        self.bottom_sheet_main_menu.open()

    def print_test(self):
        print("test")
        self.show_alert_dialog()

    def show_alert_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Dialog",
                size_hint= [0.9, None],
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="CANCEL", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color
                    ),
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="DISCARD", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color
                    ),
                ],
            )
        self.dialog.open()

    def make_card(self):

        for i in range(10):
            card = MDCard(
                orientation="vertical",
                padding="8dp",
                ripple_behavior=True,
                size_hint=[1, None],
                #on_touch_down = toast('clicked')
            )

            label_link = MDLabel(text="Card" + str(i))
            label_link.font_style = "Caption"

            label_header = MDLabel(text="Title" + str(i))
            label_header.size_hint = [1, 1]

            card.add_widget(label_link)
            card.add_widget(label_header)

            self.sm.ids.first_screen_id.ids.first_screen_box_layout.add_widget(card)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

**build_string.py**

```
helper_string = """
<MenuButton@MDIconButton>:
    icon: "menu"
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    text_color: 1,0,0,1
    halign: 'bottom'  
    on_press: app.show_main_grid_bottom_sheet()

<TButton@MDIconButton>:
    icon: "menu"
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    text_color: 1,0,0,1
    halign: 'center'  

<TitleText@MDLabel>
    pos_hint: {"center_y": .95}
    halign: "center"
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    text_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
    font_style: "Subtitle1"

ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    MainScreen:
    FirstScreen:
        id: first_screen_id
    SecondScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main_screen'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: "5dp"

        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            pos_hint: {'bottom': 1}
            #right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x: app.show_main_grid_bottom_sheet()]]
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.show_main_grid_bottom_sheet()]]   

<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'first_screen'
    BoxLayout:
        id: first_screen_box
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: "5dp"

        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            title: "First Screen"
            elevation: 5
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
            right_action_items: [["refresh", lambda x: app.make_card()]]

        ScrollView:                
            MDBoxLayout:
                id: first_screen_box_layout
                orientation: 'vertical'
                adaptive_height: True
                padding: dp(15)
                spacing: dp(5) 

        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            pos_hint: {'bottom': 1}
            #right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x: app.show_main_grid_bottom_sheet()]]
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.show_main_grid_bottom_sheet()]]   

<SecondScreen>:
    name: 'second_screen'
"""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `on_touch_down` is an event that you can bind to, it is not a property of the `MDCard` that you can set. So you can do the binding like this:

```
def make_card(self):
    for i in range(10):
        card = MDCard(
            orientation="vertical",
            padding="8dp",
            ripple_behavior=True,
            size_hint=[1, None],
            #on_touch_down = toast('clicked')
        )
        card.bind(on_touch_down=self.clicked)  # set binding

        label_link = MDLabel(text="Card" + str(i))
        label_link.font_style = "Caption"

        label_header = MDLabel(text="Title" + str(i))
        label_header.size_hint = [1, 1]

        card.add_widget(label_link)
        card.add_widget(label_header)

        self.sm.ids.first_screen_id.ids.first_screen_box_layout.add_widget(card)

# method called by binding
def clicked(self, card, touch):
    if card.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        print('clicked on', card.children[0].text)
```

Comment: Can you add an example of using an `MDCard` from a `kv` file please? I can't figure out how to use the above in that scenario.